404() error after adding custom domain on my gh-pages hosted react app
i hosted my react app on gh-pages. First it worked. But after adding  custom domain bought from SquareSpace it gave errors. Here they are:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
main.182b426c.js:1
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
manifest.json:1
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
manifest.json:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.
main.b001eb42.css:1
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
manifest.json:1
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
Here is my json:
{
"name": "javidbaku",
"version": "0.1.0",
"homepage": "/javidbaku",
"scripts": {
"predeploy": "npm run build",
"deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
"start": "react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build ",
"test": "react-scripts test",
"eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
}
I connected SquareSpace customer support. And they showed that everything is ok with domain settings. Some say it can be from my build folder. I added my build files to /javidbaku folder and pushed. Nothing changed.
